# ТГ бот на Aiogram. Бот не видит сообщения "Меню" и из-за этого его не выводит. Что делать

Tags: python, sqlite, telegram, aiogram, python-telegram-bot

У меня появилась проблема, которая, наверное, связана с машиной состояний, но я не могу понять, что не так конкретно. Я пробовал удалять функцию "add_to_menu", и уже тогда, когда я писал слово "Меню", оно выводилось из базы данных в чат. Если эта функция присутствует в коде, то бот на слово "Меню" даже не отзывается не выводит ничего в консоль (т.е. критичных ошибок нет). Также я пробовал переместить функцию "show_menu" выше чем "add_to_menu", и в этом случаи уже меню работало, но при этом другие команды не фунционировали, так же, как и "Меню" до этого.

P.S. Если для решения моей проблемы требуется доп. информация, то не стесняйтесь писать тут.)))

```
import sqlite3 as sq
from aiogram import Bot, types
from aiogram.contrib.fsm_storage.memory import MemoryStorage
from aiogram.dispatcher import Dispatcher
from aiogram.dispatcher import FSMContext
from aiogram.dispatcher.filters.state import State, StatesGroup
from aiogram.utils import executor
import bot_token

base = sq.connect('menu.db', check_same_thread=False)
cur = base.cursor()

base.execute('CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS {}(photo, name PRIMARY KEY, desc, price)'.format('menu_data'))

mod_state = False

class FSMadd(StatesGroup):
    photo = State()
    name = State()
    desc = State()
    price = State()


class FSMmod(StatesGroup):
    mod_code = State()

print('Bot works!')

storage = MemoryStorage()

bot = Bot(token=bot_token.TOKEN)
dp = Dispatcher(bot, storage=storage)


@dp.message_handler(commands='start')
async def start(message: types.Message):
    global mod_state
    if mod_state == True:
        await message.answer('Добро пожаловать в Ni Pizza, хотите измените меню?')
    else:
        await message.answer('Добро пожаловать в Ni Pizza, что изволите заказывать?')


@dp.message_handler(commands='mod', state=None)
async def get_mod(message: types.Message):
    await FSMmod.mod_code.set()
    await message.answer('Укажите код модератора, чтобы получить доступ к коммандам модератора ')


@dp.message_handler(content_types='text', state=FSMmod.mod_code)
async def get_code(message: types.Message, state: FSMContext):
    async with state.proxy() as data:
        global mod_state
        data['mod_code'] = message.text
        if data['mod_code'] == '378258' or '781241' or '912641':
            mod_state = True
            await message.answer('✅Успешный вход✅')
            await state.finish()
        elif data['mod_code'] == 'Отмена':
            await message.answer('✅Готово✅')
            await state.finish()
        else:
            await message.answer('Неверный код, попробуйте снова или напишите "Отмена"')


@dp.message_handler(content_types='text', state=None)
async def add_to_menu(message: types.Message):
    global mod_state
    if message.text == 'Добавить' and mod_state:
        await FSMadd.photo.set()
        await message.answer('Хорошо, загрузите фото пиццы')
    else:
        await message.answer('Вы не являетесь модератором данного бота')

@dp.message_handler(content_types=['photo'], state=FSMadd.photo)
async def add_to_photo(message: types.Message, state: FSMContext):
    async with state.proxy() as data:
        data['photo'] = message.photo[0].file_id
    await FSMadd.next()
    await message.answer('Отлично, теперь напишите название пиццы')


@dp.message_handler(state=FSMadd.name)
async def add_to_name(message: types.Message, state: FSMContext):
    async with state.proxy() as data:
        data['name'] = message.text
    await FSMadd.next()
    await message.answer('Отлично, теперь напишите описание пиццы')


@dp.message_handler(state=FSMadd.desc)
async def add_to_desc(message: types.Message, state: FSMContext):
    async with state.proxy() as data:
        data['desc'] = message.text
    await FSMadd.next()
    await message.answer('Отлично, теперь напишите цену пиццы')


@dp.message_handler(state=FSMadd.price)
async def add_to_price(message: types.Message, state: FSMContext):
    async with state.proxy() as data:
        data['price'] = message.text
        cur.execute('INSERT INTO menu_data VALUES(?, ?, ?, ?)',
                    (data['photo'], data['name'], data['desc'], data['price']))
    base.commit()
    await state.finish()
    await message.answer('✅Готово✅')


@dp.message_handler(content_types='text')
async def show_menu(message: types.Message):
    if message.text == 'Меню':
        await message.answer('Вот меню:')
        menu_db = cur.execute('SELECT * FROM menu_data').fetchall()
        rows = cur.execute('SELECT COUNT(name) from menu_data').fetchmany()[0][0]
        print('rows', f'{rows}\n\n', 'database', f'{menu_db}')
        for i in range(rows):
            await bot.send_photo(message.from_user.id, photo=menu_db[0 + i][0],
                                 caption=f'Название:{menu_db[0 + i][1]}\nОписание:{menu_db[0 + i][2]}\nЦена:{menu_db[0 + i][-1]}')


executor.start_polling(dp, skip_updates=True)
print('Data Base was closed successfully!')
print('Bot was disconnected from the server successfully!')
base.close()
```